# jQuery "find()" causing a win32 error in Internet Explorer 10, but not 9

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, jquery

I'm using jQuery to dynamically load some xml data.  The code works fine with no errors on all browsers except for Internet Explorer 8 and 10.  Frustratingly, it works fine in Internet Explorer 9.

Here's the code I'm using (jQuery 1.10.2):

```
$.get("xml_generator.php", {search: searchInput.value}, function(data) {
   var xml = $.parseXML(data);
   console.log($(xml).find("XmlNode").text());
});
```

If this code is ran in Internet Explorer 10, it will briefly show in the console the correct text, then I will get a "Internet Explorer has stopped working" error, and the page will refresh after it "Checks for a solution" (**Horse shit**).

If I hit debug, it tells me "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in iexplore.exe [5496]."

This happens on multiple computers and I've been searching for a solution for several days now.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**Edit**

It crashed for my client in IE 8, but when I just tested it, it seemed to work just fine in 8. So the problem seems to be unique to IE 10.

Comment: What version of jQuery? Is IE10 maybe in compatibility mode?

Comment: Can you play around and see if it is the var xml = ... line or the console.log(...) line

Comment: It's jQuery 1.10.2. 
It is not in compatibility mode.  Actually, just tested it in IE 8, see my edit.

Comment: @andrewb it is the console.log() line throwing the error.  I actually don't even have to have the ".text()" to cause it to crash.  Simply calling "$(xml).find('XmlNode')" throws the same error. 

**Edit** sorry, just to be clear, if I take out the consoloe.log line, it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: Tried the newest version of jQuery, 2.0.3, and it still crashes the same.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem was coming from a plugin I was using to stylize my select boxes called "SelectBoxIt".  Took that out, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too. It was caused by the select element not having a name attribute. Add that and it went away.